# Accessing subclass properties

Tags: c#

I have a base class called `StockItem` and one called `EcoStockItem` and a `Plate` subclass. `EcoStockItem` has a `Juice` object that is a subclass to `EcoStockItem`. In another class, I have the method `AddItem (StockItem p)`. From the `Form1` class should I send the `StockItem` item as a parameter to the method `AddItem`? I could not access the other property from subclasses. How should I do it? Create an object of `StockItem` to inherit all properties from subclasses and add it to a `StockItem` array?

```
public class StockItem
{
    private Juice newJuice;


    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StockCount { get; set; }



    public StockItem(int Id, string Name, int StockCount)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.StockCount = StockCount;

    }

    public StockItem()
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
    }

    public StockItem(Juice newJuice)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.newJuice = newJuice;
    }



    public override string ToString()
     {
         return String.Format("Id:{0} Namn:{1} Count:{2}", Id,Name,StockCount);
     }
 }


    public class EcoStockItem : StockItem
    {

        public string Markning { get; set; }
        public EcoStockItem()
        {
        }

        public EcoStockItem(string Markning)
        {
            this.Markning = Markning;
        }
        public EcoStockItem(int i, string n, int sc, string Markning):base (i,n,sc)
        {
            base.Id = i;
            base.Name = n;
            base.StockCount = sc;
            this.Markning = Markning;
        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("Mark: {0}", Markning);
        }
    }
    public class Plate : StockItem
    {
        public string Typ { get; set; }

        public Plate(string Typ)
        {
            this.Typ = Typ;
        }

        public Plate(int i, string n, int sc, string Typ):base (i,n,sc)
        {
            base.Id = i;
            base.Name = n;
            base.StockCount = sc;
            this.Typ = Typ;
        }

        public Plate()
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
        }



        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("Plate: {0}", Typ);
        }

    }

    public class Juice : EcoStockItem
    {


        public string Typ { get; set; }

        public Juice (string Typ)
        {
            this.Typ = Typ;
        }

        public Juice(int i, string n, int sc, string m,string Typ):base (i,n,sc,m)
        {
            base.Id = i;
            base.Name = n;
            base.StockCount = sc;
            base.Markning = m;
            this.Typ = Typ;
        }

        public Juice()
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("Juice: {0}", Typ);
        }

}

class Stock
{

    public StockItem[] StockItems = new StockItem[10];


    public void AddItem(StockItem item)
    {
        int index = GetCount();
        StockItems[index] = item;
        Form1.myForm.textBoxTest.Text = StockItems[index].ToString();
    }

    public int GetCount()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < StockItems.Length; n++)
        {

            if (StockItems[n] != null)
            {

                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }


}
```

}

```
class Form1


private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        newStockItem = new StockItem();
        newStockItem.Id = id;
        newStockItem.Name = name;
        newStockItem.StockCount = stockcount;
        newEcoStockItem = new EcoStockItem ();
        newEcoStockItem.Markning = markning;
        newPlate = new Plate();
        newPlate.Typ = typ;
        newJuice = new Juice();
        newJuice.Typ = jtyp;
        //StockItem p = new StockItem(...........); ?????????????

        Stock stock = new Stock();
        //stock.AddItem(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. Inheritance provides an *is a* relationship, so this should work fine:

   ```
   newJuice = new Juice();
   newJuice.Typ = jtyp;

   Stock stock = new Stock();
   //stock.AddItem(newJuice);   // this works since Juice IS a StoceItem
   ```
2. To store a variable number of items in a collection a `List`will be MUCH more efficient:

   ```
   class Stock
   {
       public List<StockItem> StockItems = new List<StockItem>();

       public void AddItem(StockItem item)
       {
           StockItems.Add(item);
           Form1.myForm.textBoxTest.Text = item.ToString();
       }

       public int GetCount()
       {
           return StockItems.Count;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Do not reference your form directly from the class - this may be why you;re not seeing the results you expect.  Typically the form either *extracts* data from the objects it creates or uses *events* to get information pushed to it.

Comment: This is a school project and program skeleton is made for uml. Really need help with this. Is attached with this for one week.

Comment: #1 should answer your question - 2 and 3 are just suggestions.  IF you _still_ have a problem add more detail (specific error message?) to your question.

Comment: Array item in index 0 must contain both property fron the base class and subclasses. I do not know how I'll create reference of StockItem that will contain all subatributer and send the pair angles to the Add method ..

Comment: Read up on casting and polymorphism. Array item 0 _will_be the base class (and have its properties). It _may_ also be a subclass - although you man't know which type without trying to cast it or using reflection to determine the type.